# How can I tell what readPreference MongoDB queries hitting my database are using?

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I have a MongoDB 2.4 replica set and have a node.js application that is coded to use `readPreference: 'secondaryPreferred'` in most--but not all--situations.

I'd like to verify on the server that the read preferences are as intended for various queries. Is there a way when viewing current ops or profiling I can see what read preference the query was run with?

Comment: use db.serverStatus().opcounters on each DB server compare 'query' count pre-querying and post-querying. for entire list of db server status, use db.serverStatus().

Comment: A read preference is a client/driver-side concept. The server is not aware of the read preference of a request so you can't verify read preference on the server side. You can verify that some queries are sent to secondaries via, e.g., mongostat or the method in the previous comment.

Comment: Thank you for db.serverStatus().opcounters info, really useful in trying to tell what queries are hitting which server :) that should be an answer